# Connecting to API with Angular Webapp using Minikube and Kubernetes

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, minikube

I'm trying to learn Kubernetes and would like to create a simple example of an Angular frontend in a Docker container connecting to a .NET Core API also on a Docker container. I am able to successfully create both the API and the frontend and can see the result on the browse but struggle to retrieve information from the API on the frontend. As the IP of the API changes I can't hardcode those values in the Angular app before building the image but using the DNS name doesn't seem to work either.

Currently I have the following in my Angular app:

```
SERVER_URI: 'http://budgetlist-api:50605/'
```

backend-api.service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bucketlist-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: bucketlist-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 50605
  type: ClusterIP
```

frontend-app.service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bucketlist-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: bucketlist-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 4200
      targetPort: 4200
  type: NodePort
```

The Dockerfile for my Angular app is:

```
FROM node:12.2.0
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . .

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I'm not sure what else is needed but I'm happy to add more information if required. Any help is appreciated as I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

Comment: I assume the problem is that you have 2 deployments and 2 services on minikube and you can connect by using the ip but not dns name?  Can you [exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) into 1 of your deployments and curl the other one dns service? So for example I have some ubuntu pod and nginx pod, both with services, and I exec into ubuntu pod and use `curl -v my-nginx` ( nginx service) and the response is `http/1.1 200 OK`. Could you make something like that and let me know if it works for you or you can curl only the endpoints(IP)?

Comment: Hi that's correct. So I have a deployment/service for my backend-api and I have a deployment/service for my angular app. I did as you suggested.

```kubectl exec -it frontend-app -- /bin/bash``` and then ```curl -v backend-api``` this returned the same cluster ip address as if I was to do a ```kubectl get service```

Comment: So if I unserstood you correctly and connect between both of them is fine then it would be the angular code itself which I'm not familiar with, from kubernetes side I could recommend to use nginx as  container which would proxy pass to backend, more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/).

Answer (score 0):

Your backend service is ClusterIP, so it can only be accessed from inside Minikube cluster
Angular is running from outside cluster (from your browser)

You should change backend service type to NodePort or LoadBalancer. Or use Ingress Controller.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bucketlist-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: bucketlist-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 50605
      nodePort: 30100
  type: NodePort
```

And use SERVER_URI as

```
SERVER_URI: 'http://budgetlist-api:30100/'
```